# var imgLoader = document.getElementById("imgLoader"); always null

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I created a simple Datalist in ASP.net that contains pictures.
when I clicked on an image, I want to display it in a small separated window like a popup .
I added a Loader image to show it before the selected image.
You can see below the asp.net code for the popup window:

```
<div id="divImage" >
<table style="height: 100%; width: 100%">
    <tr>
        <td valign="middle" align="center" colspan = "3" style     ="height:500px;">
            <img id="imgLoader" runat="server" alt=""
             src="~/Images/loader.gif" />
            <img id="imgFull" alt="" src="" 
             style="display: none;
            height: 500px;width: 600px" />
        </td>
```

In the javascript code I got the variable (imgLoader = NULL).

```
var imgLoader = document.getElementById("imgLoader");
```

Do you have an idea why I got a NULL result ?

the LoadDiv function:

```
 function LoadDiv(url, lnk) {
            var img = new Image();
            var bcgDiv = document.getElementById("divBackground");
            var imgDiv = document.getElementById("divImage");
            var imgFull = document.getElementById("imgFull");
            var imgLoader = document.getElementById("imgLoader");
            var dl = document.getElementById("<%=DataList1.ClientID%>");
            var imgs = dl.getElementsByTagName("img");

            CurrentPage = GetImageIndex(lnk.parentNode) + 1;
            imgLoader.style.display = "block";
            img.onload = function () {
                imgFull.src = img.src;
                imgFull.style.display = "block";
                imgLoader.style.display = "none";
            };
            img.src = url;
            Prepare_Pager(imgs.length);
            var width = document.body.clientWidth;
            if (document.body.clientHeight > document.body.scrollHeight) {
                bcgDiv.style.height = document.body.clientHeight + "px";
            }
            else {
                bcgDiv.style.height = document.body.scrollHeight + "px";
            }

            imgDiv.style.left = (width - 650) / 2 + "px";
            imgDiv.style.top = "20px";
            bcgDiv.style.width = "100%";

            bcgDiv.style.display = "block";
            imgDiv.style.display = "block";
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: When do you run your script? Are you sure that the img exist before to access it?

Comment: it is the LoadDiv function

Comment: Please post the LoadDiv function too

Comment: Is the formatting of your code the issue - look at how your <image/> is split over several lines. Could this be fooling the parser? Try putting all the tag on one line with no line break.

Comment: I tried to put all the tag on one line but I have always the same error.

Answer (score 2):

Because the `<img>` is marked with `runat="server"` and that means the `id` will be used internally be Asp.net to reference this component, while the actual element id (in the client-side) would be something different.

Try this instead:

```
var imgLoader = document.getElementById("<%=imgLoader.ClientID%>");
```

Alternatively, if you're doing anything with this component in the server side, you can simply omit the `runat="server"`.